# Ayuda bucles anidados en python - leer dos ficheros

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, ssh

Tengo un script donde quiero leer de un fichero txt un listado de IPs para entrar por ssh a los routers y otro fichero txt para leer los comandos que quiero lanzar en los routers.

El problema es que en el primer bucle entra y lee la primera ip, después entra en el segundo bucle, lee los comandos y los ejecuta en el primer router. El problema viene cuando tiene que entrar en el segundo router y ejecutar los mismos comandos, el script termina y en el excel si me ha creado la hoja con los demas routers pero solo ha enviado los comandos en el primer router. En los demás routers (IPs del primer bucle) no lanza los comandos.

También tengo añadido (worksheet.set_default_row(30)) para que las 30 primeras celdas tengan altura dinámica y según el comando aparezca en dicha celda toda la info, pero pone tamaño determinado y tengo ue ampliar manualmente la celda para ver toda la información. ¿Como debería hacerlo?

Utilizo xlsxwriter para después poder pintar gráficas.

```
ip_add_file = open(r'/root/Escritorio/script python/ix/listaIX.txt','r') # a simple list of IP addresses you want to connect to each one on a new line
comando_add_file = open (r'/root/Escritorio/script python/ix/comandoIX.txt','r')

for host in ip_add_file: 
    host = host.strip() 
    device = ConnectHandler (device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password, port=port)
    pro = device.find_prompt() #saca el prompt del equipo
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(pro)
    worksheet.set_default_row(30)
    row_ = 0
    col_ = 0
    for command in comando_add_file:
        command = command.strip() 
        print(pro)
        worksheet.write(row_, col_, pro + str(command))
        row_ +=1
        output = device.send_command( str(command) ) 
        print(output)
        worksheet.write(row_, col_, output)
        row_ +=1

    device.disconnect() # se desconecta del equipo

workbook.close()
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` retorna un objeto `TextIOWrapper` que representa un buffer de secuencia de texto. Para marcar la posición  en el stream se usa un marcador de posición o "puntero" que indica la posición actual de lectura y que se va incrementando al tiempo que se leen datos del archivo.

Por otro lado, el objeto actúa como un iterador, de forma que al recorrerlo con un `for` internamente se llama al método `newline` por cada vuelta del `for`, retornando una linea en cada una, hasta recorrer el archivo al completo. En cada vuelta el "puntero" se incrementa para marcar desde dónde empezar a leer en la próxima iteración o llamada al método `__next__` por lo que al terminar de leer el archivo el puntero estará situado al final de éste. Si en esta situación intentas obtener una nueva línea (vía `next(file)`) obtendrás un error `StopIteration`, que indica que el iterador está "consumido". Como con cualquier iterador en esta situación, si iteras con un `for` sobre el de nuevo el ciclo no itera ninguna vez porque no hay items disponibles.  Así mismo `read` y `readline` retornan una cadena vacía y `readlines` una lista vacía.

La solución es usar el método `seek()` que permite cambiar la posición del "puntero", de forma que `seek(0)` lo vuelve a colocar al inicio del archivo y por tanto puedes volver a iterar sobre él. Otra posibilidad es almacenar todo el archivo en una lista y luego iterar las veces que quieras sobre ellas, dependiendo del caso puede ser más eficiente que leer repetidamente del archivo, pero el problema es que usas siempre más memoria al cargar el archivo al completo, lo cual puede ser prohibitivo si este es muy extenso.

En cuanto a la altura dinámica, ten en cuenta que con `set_default_row` lo que haces es asignar la altura por defecto para todas las filas a 30. En principio puedes hacer que se ajuste la altura al texto [mediante formato](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_text_wrap)

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_text_wrap()
cell_format.set_align('vjustify')

ip_path = '/root/Escritorio/script python/ix/listaIX.txt'
co_path = '/root/Escritorio/script python/ix/comandoIX.txt'
with open(ip_path) as ip_add_file, open(co_path) as comando_add_file:
    for host in ip_add_file: 
        host = host.strip() 
        device = ConnectHandler(
            device_type=platform,
            ip=host,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            port=port
            )
        pro = device.find_prompt() #saca el prompt del equipo
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(pro)
        worksheet.set_default_row(30)
        row_ = 0
        col_ = 0
        for command in comando_add_file:
            command = command.strip() 
            print(pro)
            worksheet.write(row_, col_, pro + str(command), cell_format)
            row_ += 1
            output = device.send_command( str(command) ) 
            print(output)
            worksheet.write(row_, col_, output, cell_format)
            row_ += 1

        comando_add_file.seek(0)
        device.disconnect() # se desconecta del equipo

    workbook.close()
```